# The problem of navigation of information from the presentation form to the controller in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using WebImageProcessor.Models;
using WebImageProcessor.ViewModel;
using WebImageProcessor.ViewModel.Models;

namespace WebImageProcessor.Areas.Admin.Controllers
{
    [Area("Admin")]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ImageProcessorDbContext db;

        public HomeController(ImageProcessorDbContext context) 
        {
            db = context;
        }

        [Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            AdminPageViewModel usersInf = new AdminPageViewModel();

            usersInf.FullUsersInf = db.AppUsers
                .Select(user => new FullUserInfModel
                {
                    Nickname = user.Nickname,
                    Name = user.Name,
                    Surname = user.Surname,
                    Password = user.Password,
                    RoleName = user.Role.RoleName
                })
                .ToList();

            return View(usersInf);
        }

        [Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ChangeUserRoleAsync(string? nickname)
        {
            if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(nickname))
            {
                AppUser user = db.AppUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Nickname == nickname);

                user.Role.RoleName = ChackAdminRole(nickname) ? "user" : "admin";

                db.AppUsers.Update(user);
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        private bool ChackAdminRole(string roleName)
        {
            if (roleName == "admin")
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a partial view:

```
@model WebImageProcessor.ViewModel.AdminPageViewModel

<!-- Table head options start -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h4 class="card-title">Редагування користувачів</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="card-content collapse show">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead class="thead-dark">
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">Nickname</th>
                                <th scope="col">Ім'я</th>
                                <th scope="col">Призвіще</th>
                                <th scope="col">Пароль</th>
                                <th scope="col">Роль</th>
                                <th scope="col">Змінити роль</th>
                                <th scope="col">Видалити</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach(var user in Model.FullUsersInf)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <th>@user.Nickname</th>
                                    <th>@user.Name</th>
                                    <th>@user.Surname</th>
                                    <th>@user.Password</th>
                                    <th>@user.RoleName</th>
                                    <th>
                                        <form asp-area="Admin" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="ChangeUserRoleAsync" method="post" asp-route-nickname="@user.Nickname">
                                            @if(user.RoleName == "user")
                                            {
                                                <input class="btn btn-info adminTableBtn" type="submit" value="на admin" />
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                <input class="btn btn-info adminTableBtn" type="submit" value="на user" />
                                            }
                                        </form>
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        <form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="DeleteUser" method="post" asp-route-id="@user.Nickname">
                                            <input class="btn btn-info adminTableBtn" type="submit" value="видалити" />
                                        </form>
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                            }                           
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Table head options end -->
```

And my `Program.cs` file:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using WebImageProcessor.Models;
using WebImageProcessor.Services.Image_process.Interfeces;
using WebImageProcessor.Services.Image_process.Realization;
using WebImageProcessor.Services.Image_Process.Interfeces;

namespace WebImageProcessor
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            // Add file with configuration, which contains paths 
            builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("pathsSettings.json");

            // Add services to the container.
            builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
            builder.Services.AddDbContext<ImageProcessorDbContext>();
            builder.Services.AddScoped<IDetectObject, YoloV8ProcessImgService>();
            builder.Services.AddScoped<IPhotoInformation, PhotoInfYoloV8Service>();

            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie(options =>
                {
                    options.LoginPath = "/LoginLogoutReg/Login";
                    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Home/Index";
                });
            builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            var app = builder.Build();

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "admin",
                pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            app.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            app.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that when I click the role change button, an error is displayed that the path is not known:

> Host page not found localhost No web pages found for web address https://localhost:7134/Admin/Home/ChangeUserRoleAsync?nickname=DewoLanosOneLove
> HTTP ERROR 404

I've been trying to find information about this but everything I've tried has not worked.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how, but I solved the navigation problem, in a way that is not clear to me, I rewrote the method, but removed the async part, and everything started working. I don't know how it works, because I am sure that the names of what is presented in the controller were the same and written in English.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).